# Can a metaclass manipulate naked expressions from a class' scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

With a metaclass and the `__prepare__` method, it is possible to intercept attributes before they are added to a class' namespace. Is there a way, *as hacky as it is*, to intercept naked expressions from the class' scope.

```
class Class(metaclass=Metaclass):
    # Would it be possible to intercept those:
    1
    2
    3
```

The closest syntax I have found that allows something similar is to reserve the `_` name for such expressions.

```
class ClassNamespace(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.expressions = []
        super().__init__()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key == '_':
            self.expressions.append(value)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)

class Metaclass(type):
    def __prepare__(metacls, name):
        return ClassNamespace()

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):

        # Do something with the expressions
        print(namespace.expressions)

        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)

class Class(metaclass=Metaclass):
    _ = 1
    _ = 2
    _ = 3

# prints: [1, 2, 3]
```

It is clean, but is there a way to recover 1, 2 and 3 without using assignments?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "intercept" them? i.e. What happens to these values?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this cannot be done. Since the reference count of `1`, `2`, and `3` would be zero, it seems they'd be deallocated.

Comment: @martineau in the case of attributes, ClassNamepsace.__setitem__ is passed a key and value. Would there be an equivalent for naked expressions, where the output is passed to a function of the metaclass or of the namespace.

Knowing how bytecode for naked expression is treated, it would need to be through a hack.

Comment: You'll need to have at least one assignment for the `ClassNamespace.__setitem__()` method to even be invoked. Would something like `_expressions = 1, 2, 3` (or  `_ = 1, 2, 3`) be an acceptable compromise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No metaclass mechanisms support what you're trying to do. `1` doesn't generate a name lookup, so `__prepare__` doesn't help. Heck, `1` as a statement on its own doesn't generate any bytecode at all, because it gets optimized out.

Even if you were willing to go so far as having the metaclass locate the function object for the class body and *replace its bytecode* with instrumented bytecode to try to capture these expressions, it would still find no trace of the original expressions in the bytecode, and there would be nothing to instrument. Also, the metaclass has no way to get involved in the original compilation pass for the class body.

The most plausible (still utterly crazy) option seems to be to have the metaclass locate the original source code for the class, parse it, modify the AST, recompile, and replace the original code object for the class body. This would never work in interactive mode (since the source code isn't kept in interactive mode), among the many other reasons why this is a bad idea.

Comment: I thought about the AST trick, the problem is that if an expression was to be a function, it would call it twice. Such as solution would need to raise an exception to stop the parsing of the class, then parse it with its own parser. Wait... that might be it!

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: Are you thinking of replacing the class body after it runs? I'm talking about replacing the class body *before* it runs. `__prepare__` gives the metaclass a window of opportunity to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "clean", but it is without assignment:

```
class ClassNamespace(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.expressions = []
        self['record'] = self.expressions.append #make a special function to used for "clean" expressions

class Metaclass(type):
    def __prepare__(metacls, name):
        return ClassNamespace()

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        print(namespace.expressions)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)

class Class(metaclass=Metaclass):
    record(1) #identifiers are first looked for in the class namespace, where we set "record" to append to the expressions list
    record(2)
    record(3)
```

You can also set the special function to be _: `_(1)` might look prettier than `record(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could sort of do it with a class decorator. For example:

```
class Metaclass(type):
    @staticmethod
    def handle_expressions(args):
        print(args)

def expressions(*args):
    """ Class decorator that passes expressions to Metaclass. """
    def decorator(cls):
        Metaclass.handle_expressions(args)  # Pass to metaclass method.
        return cls
    return decorator

#  Sample usage.
@expressions(1, 1+1, 2*2-1)
class Class(metaclass=Metaclass):
    pass
```

Would print:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

Note if you want the called metaclass method to be able to do something to or otherwise be able to reference the class being constructed, you could make `handle_expressions()` a `@classmethod` instead of a `staticmethod`.